# ImageIO ValueError in exe made by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made an exe to read images including gifs using pyinstaller. However, the exe can't read gif and the below error occurs. I have installed the latest version of imageio and the program works in interpreter. Could you advise? Thanks in advance.

The line raising error:

cv_gif = imageio.mimread(pic_path)

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Image Viewer.py", line 3085, in <module>
  File "Image Viewer.py", line 522, in go
  File "Image Viewer.py", line 1264, in ShowANI
  File "imageio\core\functions.py", line 247, in mimread
  File "imageio\core\imopen.py", line 277, in imopen
ValueError: Could not find a backend to open `C:\Users\simon\Practice\testdir3\alpaca.gif`` with iomode `rI`.
Based on the extension, the following plugins might add capable backends:
  pillow:  pip install imageio[pillow]
  GIF-PIL:  pip install imageio[pillow]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem.
This might have something to do with the new feature of imageio introduced in version 2.11.0: Choose plugin based on extension and plugin lazy-import. Revert back to 2.10.5 solves the problem.

Comment: Indeed there is an issue raised about it. https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/684

Comment: That helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just manually copied the folder `\Lib\site-packages\imageio` and replaced the `imagoio` folder of the `exe`, then it works.