# Issues after converting py to exe by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, scikit-image

I have problem with my desktop app. When I execute it via PyCharm, I don't have any problem, but when I convert it to exe file via pyintaller, I can't do basics operations. When I try to open an image I got this error in console:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  File "GUI.py", line 111, in fill_list_from_folder
  File "FileMenagment.py", line 60, in read_file
  File "skimage\io\_io.py", line 53, in imread
  File "skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 207, in call_plugin
  File "skimage\io\_plugins\imageio_plugin.py", line 10, in imread
  File "imageio\core\functions.py", line 159, in imread
  File "imageio\core\imopen.py", line 277, in imopen
ValueError: Could not find a backend to open `C:\Users\szotm\Desktop\Zamek\lot1_25_100.jpg`` with iomode `ri`.
```

It show works only for grayscale .tif files. I can't open .jpg and .png
I use scikit-image library, because I have to get into all pixels values.
There is function which I use to open it:

```
    def read_file(self, x: int):
        self.readed_file = io.imread(self.file_list[x])
```

It open 1 file from file_list, file_list can't be empty and in file_list can be only files ends with .jpg, .png, .tif, .tiff, .jpeg.

This is only one problem that I have noticed, because I can't go further without open files, which I can't now, so please for help. Possible then I haven't notice that solution is somewhere in Internet, but you can trust me, then I would not wasting time of other people, without research at least a couple of days.

Comment: Do you use one-file or one-directory option?

Comment: I use both, without --windowed option to see console, in case of errors like that.

Comment: While pasting the ValueError, did you add the extra quote (') yourself ?-> `C:\Users\szotm\Desktop\Zamek\lot1_25_100.jpg``

Comment: I notice this extra ' and I don't know where it happend, when I modified read_file function by adding print(self.file_list[x]) it shows path without extra '

Comment: Ooouh. I missunderstand your question, I don't add it, I had copy paste whole ValueError. I change nothing there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209755/imageio-valueerror-in-exe-made-by-pyinstaller/70255832
There is solution of this problem. Thanks everybody for help.